# how to do collision detection in java

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-android

I'm trying to go collusion detection in java for cocos2d for android and heres the code I have

```
float oldx = player.getPosition().x;
float oldy = player.getPosition().y;
if((player.getPosition().y + player.getContentSize().height > building1.getPosition().y) &&
   (player.getPosition().y < building1.getPosition().y + building1.getContentSize().height) && 
   (player.getPosition().x + player.getContentSize().width > building1.getPosition().x) &&
   (player.getPosition().x < building1.getPosition().x + building1.getContentSize().width))
{
    player.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(oldx, oldy));
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't work... why?

Comment: I would love collusion detection for the CIA and the petroleum industry :-)

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: well the code for collusion detection works fine but its not setting the players position back.. :/

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `oldx` and `oldy` to `player.getPosition().x` and `player.getPosition().y`, respectively. You are using exactly the same checks in your collision detection if-statement so you are essentially setting the position to the same spot it was.

You need to know the position the player wants to move to prior to doing the check that the collision occurs, and then just not allow the player to move there (i.e. don't update their X and Y).